# How to copy the last node in a linked list into a variable then delete the original in the list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

Basically I want to 'take' the last element. Deleting it from the list but before that, it is stored in a variable so that it can still be accessed as a separate variable but not part of the list anymore.

**EDIT**

This is the code for a function that is supposed to return the last node as a variable but delete it from the list:

```
struct node * take_last_node()
{
    struct node * back = top;
    struct node * cursor;
    while (back->link != NULL)
    {
        cursor = back;
        back = back->link;
    }
    cursor->link = NULL; //this is the problem
    return back;
}
```

Where cursor is supposed to be the second last node before the last node is deleted and the back is the very last node that will be deleted from the list and returned as a variable. Without the commented line, the cursor and back points to the correct nodes however obviously the back node is not deleted. So I added that line so the back node gets deleted from the list but it's still saved in a separate variable. Suppose I have a list from top to bottom: 4, 3, 2, 1, NULL. With the commented line added in this function, the last node does get deleted but then the cursor and back struct variables get shifted up and instead this function returns 2 while the cursor itself points to 3 when instead I want the cursor to point to 2 with the final list looking like so: 4, 3, 2, NULL and the function returning 1.

**This is the full code. It is not the real one but it perfectly creates the problem I am currently having with the real one:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct token
{
    int type;
    char * value;
};

union data
{
    int treenode;
    struct token token;
};

struct node
{
    enum Node_Type {TREE_NODE, TOKEN} type;
    union data data;
    struct node * link;
};

struct node * top = NULL;
struct node * lookahead = NULL;

struct node * peek(int placement_of_node_from_top)
{
    int n = placement_of_node_from_top;
    struct node * temp = top;
    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n-1; ++i)
        {
            if (temp->link == NULL)
                break;
            temp = temp->link;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("[InternalError] Void stack.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return temp;
}

void pop(int placement_of_node_from_top)
{
    int n = placement_of_node_from_top;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; ++i)
    {
        top = top->link;
        if (top == NULL)
        {
            printf("[InternalError] Void stack.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void push(union data data, enum Node_Type type)
{
    struct node * temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->type = type;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->link = top;
    top = temp;
}

struct node * retokenise()
{
    struct node * back = top;
    struct node * cursor = NULL;
    while (back->link != NULL)
    {
        cursor = back;
        back = back->link;
    }
    cursor->link = NULL;
    return back;
}

int main()
{
    union data data1, data2, data3, data4;
    data1.token.type = 0;
    data1.token.value = "Test";
    data2.token.type = 1;
    data2.token.value = "String";
    data3.token.type = 2;
    data3.token.value = "Hello";
    data4.token.type = 3;
    data4.token.value = "World";

    push(data1, TOKEN);
    push(data2, TOKEN);
    push(data3, TOKEN);
    push(data4, TOKEN);

    printf("TAKE (%d: %s)\n", retokenise()->data.token.type, retokenise()->data.token.value);

    while (peek(1) != NULL)
    {
        if (peek(1)->link == NULL)
        {
            printf("(%d: %s)\n", peek(1)->data.token.type, peek(1)->data.token.value);
            break;
        }
        printf("(%d: %s)\n", peek(1)->data.token.type, peek(1)->data.token.value);
        pop(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a fine idea to me. Where's your code?

Comment: @John Smith " Deleting it from the list but before that, it is stored in a variable" - it is the solution!

Comment: 1. Unlink the node from the list, updating **all** pointers that potentially point to it accordingly. 2. Copy/move the value from the now-orphaned node to some return/output target. 3. Delete the node. 4. Return the fruits reaped from (2). That's it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Here's the code.. sorry kind of late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you mistakes below:-

```
printf("TAKE (%d: %s)\n", retokenise()->data.token.type, retokenise()->data.token.value);
```

In the above `printf` your are calling `retokenise()` twice. In the first call it return the last node and you are printing the value of `data.token.type` and in the second call it returns the current last node and you are printing `data.token.value`. These two values are from two different node. In both calls of `retokenise()` is returning two different nodes, not the same one. Remember that each call it removes a node and return its address pointer. One big mistake is, you did not even release the memory and that will leads to memory leak.

Correct it like below:-

```
 struct node *p = retokenise();
 printf("TAKE (%d: %s)\n", p->data.token.type, p->data.token.value);
 free(p);
```

Correct your remaining codes like above for all the function which returns different node pointer in each call, for example `pop()`, but do not call `free()` function as you are not deleting the node here. Do it carefully. And let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: My code is almost exactly like yours as written in the edit section in the question that I have updated. The problem is written there too.

Comment: @JohnSmith, your code is fine for me. It returning the last node of the list and current last node is pointed by pointer `cursor`. What wrong here `cursor->link = NULL;` ? the statement is perfectly fine. What is your problem at the moment?

Comment: The problem is written in the edit section. I have a list containing from top to bottom: 4, 3, 2, 1, NULL. This function returns 2 while deleting 1 so the final list becomes 4, 3, 2, NULL however this is not exactly what I want. It does successfully delete 1 but what I also want is, save 1 to a variable before it is actually deleted from the list. So what I want the function to do is make the list like so: 4, 3, 2, NULL and return 1. Not 2.

Comment: @JohnSmith, The above function in your code must return the pointer of the last node only and as per your example it must return 1. I think when you created the list there must be some issue. Before deleting the node just print the whole list first and check whether list is perfect. Better put all of your codes.

Comment: @JohnSmith, See my latest answer with correction. You did mistakes in your code and that is the reason it was printing wrong values.

Comment: Do I call free() whenever I delete a node?

Comment: Yes, you need to release the memory of that deleted node.